# Visual Studio C++ printing tab \t takes up 119 whitespaces

Tags: c++, visual-studio, terminal, character, whitespace

I have an issue that comes up whenever I print a tab `\t` to CMD with `printf()` in C++ using Visual Studio.  Instead of taking up the usual 4 or so spaces, the `\t` occupies 119 spaces, throwing off any formatting involving tabs.

I have tried a python script and it puts the tabs out as I would expect, do you guys know of a setting I might have changed that would do this? I would like to avoid reinstalling VS if possible.

A minimal sample of code that causes this:

```
#include<stdafx.h>

int main()
{
    printf("\tHello");
    getchar();
}
```

OUTPUT

```
                                                                                                               Hello
```

Some further testing:

When I redirect the output to a file like so:

```
$ ConsoleApplication1.exe > "test.txt"
```

Inside test.txt is what I want, a single tab followed by Hello

I have tested with multiple tabs and they all give the massive whitespace in CMD and work fine when written to file.

To make things extra confusing, as I rebuild and run this a few times, some of the times the tabs work fine in CMD, most of the time I get the 119 whitespaces.  I have not found a reliable pattern here.

---

## Another round of tests:

I compiled with gcc the following code:

```
#include<cstdio>
int main()
{
    printf("\tHello");
    getchar();
}
```

With the following command:

```
gcc ConsoleApplication1.cpp -o testfile.exe
```

And still get the large tab when I run testfile.exe

If I use type test.txt, where test.txt is the redirected CMD output from above, I get a proper tab followed by Hello.  So my CMD can handle tabs, just not the ones coming from a C++ executable....

Resetting the Visual Studio settings did not fix the problem, nor did restarting the computer.

---

## More testing:

I found some details and think I messed up identifying things earlier.  I get no issue running these with Command Prompt, typing `testfile.exe` in a Command Prompt I opened myself works as expected.  I DO get the issue when I build and run the file from VS, or I double click it in file explorer, but this exe window is different to Command Prompt.

Results of CHCP:

```
Active code page: 437
```

A .bat file gives me tabs as expected, when called via command prompt OR double clicked

---

## More details:

This is a Visual C++ Win32 Console Application with nothing but the .cpp file above and the included header file.

Contents of ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x64">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x64">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <VCProjectVersion>15.0</VCProjectVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{7F82BA40-D2C2-4FF6-8899-42F2124F499D}</ProjectGuid>
    <Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>
    <RootNamespace>ConsoleApplication1</RootNamespace>
    <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0.14393.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v141</PlatformToolset>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v141</PlatformToolset>
    <WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v141</PlatformToolset>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v141</PlatformToolset>
    <WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="Shared">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <LinkIncremental>true</LinkIncremental>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <LinkIncremental>true</LinkIncremental>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <LinkIncremental>false</LinkIncremental>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <LinkIncremental>false</LinkIncremental>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
      <Optimization>MaxSpeed</Optimization>
      <FunctionLevelLinking>true</FunctionLevelLinking>
      <IntrinsicFunctions>true</IntrinsicFunctions>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;NDEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <EnableCOMDATFolding>true</EnableCOMDATFolding>
      <OptimizeReferences>true</OptimizeReferences>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
      <Optimization>MaxSpeed</Optimization>
      <FunctionLevelLinking>true</FunctionLevelLinking>
      <IntrinsicFunctions>true</IntrinsicFunctions>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>NDEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <EnableCOMDATFolding>true</EnableCOMDATFolding>
      <OptimizeReferences>true</OptimizeReferences>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Text Include="ReadMe.txt" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="stdafx.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="targetver.h" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="ConsoleApplication1.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="stdafx.cpp">
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Are you sure the program output has the spaces? You can check this by redirecting the output into a file and check if there is a tab or spaces.

Comment: Can you repro this without the Visual Studio vcxproj system? For example, compile your min repro cpp file shared above via commandline and execute.

cl main.cpp

Comment: It seems that your terminal does wired things. What happens when you run `type test.txt`?

Comment: I sugges you could try to [Reset settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/environment-settings?view=vs-2019#reset-settings) the visual studio.

Comment: Ok, so it is not Visual Studio related, since it repros without it. Is this the default Windows command prompt? Or are you using MINGW or Windows Subsystem for Linux? If CMD, what is your Active code page? Check by running chcp

Comment: Also, to see if it is specific to the exe or your cmd prompt, make a batch file that echoes a TAB. This line should do it (replace <TAB> with actual tab): @echo a<TAB>b

Comment: can you share the vcxproj file for this project? Also, what type of project is this? Empty C++ Windows Console App?

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed? If so, try disabling them.